# How to compare two turtles in Netlogo by going through a list of their attributes?

Tags: netlogo

My turtles have more than 30 attributes of boolean values and I would like to use a foreach loop to compare turtles and rank them based on their similarity without the need to compare each attribute individually. I might be missing an obvious point here, I have tried having a list of attributes, but it didn't work and all turtles got the maximum similarity score.

Comment: Use `sort-by` once you have your measure, but "based on their similarity" to what?  If to one particular turtle, use Hamming distance. If to the whole group, look at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X06001909

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code that calculates the Hamming distance between two lists. Note that the very clever `reduce` code is taken directly from the NetLogo dictionary.

```
to testme
  let ll1 (list TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE)
  let ll2 (list TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE)
  let ll3 ( map = ll2 ll1 )
  show ll3
  show reduce [ [occurrence-count next-item] ->
    ifelse-value (next-item) [occurrence-count + 1] [occurrence-count] ] (fput 0 ll3)
end
```

If you were wanting to calculate the similarity score of a pair of turtles, you could turn this into a reporter that takes the two turtles as arguments. But it's not clear that comparing two turtles is what you want to do, so I haven't written code for that.